# How do I change the innerHTML of a <form-check form-switch> element in js?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

This is my `html` code:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" name="emp">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mySwitch">EmpName</label>
</div>
```

This is my `js`:

```
var Switch = document.getElementById("mySwitch");
Switch.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(Switch.value=="yes")
        Switch.innerHTML="EmpNo";
    else
        Switch.innerHTML="EmpName";
})
```

I don't know why the text isn't changing. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting the `<input>` element, but the one containing the text is the `<label>` element next to the input.

```
const input = document.getElementById("mySwitch");
const label = input.nextElementSibling.
```

Listen for  the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event on the `input` instead of click. The change event will be triggered whenever the input has been checked or unchecked and is more reliable for this case.

Then check the `.checked` property on the input to see of the checkbox has been checked or not. Instead of modifying the `.innerHTML` property, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the changed text.

```
input.addEventListener('change' function() {
  if (input.checked) {
    label.textContent = 'EmpNo';
  } else {
    label.textContent = 'EmpName';
  }
});
```